# Search for first part Multidimensional Array ActionScript 3

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, multidimensional-array

I was wondering can you have a long array and then use them like a short array, The best way to explain my question is in code.

```
  var Cars_Sold:Array = new Array():

  Cars_Sold.push([0,5,3,7,8,9,1]); // each section of information is one day so 
  Monday no cars was sold Tuesday 5 cars was sold ect.
```

Is there a way by using array "Cars_sold" to see how many cars was sold on Wednesday?, This is just a general question, so I do not need alternative method if this is not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `Cars_Sold[i][j];` should do it.

Assuming that the Array [0, 5, 3, 7, 8, 9, 1] corresponds to the days of the week in your example.

However note that

```
var Cars_Sold:Array = new Array();
Cars_Sold.push([0,5,3,7,8,9,1]);
```

is different from

```
var Cars_Sold:Array = [0,5,3,7,8,9,1];
```

The first one is a multidimensional array so to speak and the second one is a linear array.
But why would you use a multidimensional array when only "days of the week" is the parameter for your problem?